# How to play video on MPMoviePlayerController using ALAsset URL?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, alassetslibrary, alasset

How to play video on MPMoviePlayerController using ALAsset URL?

I tried to directly give the ALAsset URL to MPMoviePlayer using `setContentURL:` method, but it did not work.

```
if (!self.moviePlayer)
{
    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
}

[self.moviePlayer setContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:playPath]];
self.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay=YES;
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

[ScrollView addSubview: [self.moviePlayer view]];

self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mahesh can you please try with this :

```
self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile ;
```